# Plot dynamically added array elements using Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/ms91r4pr/)

The fiddle is a mimic of a real case scenario wherein I get the data from sensors (MQTT)

dataArray[] is populated every 1 second. To show the same I have a button which on click adds an array element to dataArray.

The plotting of graph starts after timeout of 5 seconds. If the button was clicked for 'x' times within 5 seconds of DOM ready, 'x' points will be plotted.

```
$("#addToArray").click(function() {
  dataArray.push((payload));
  console.log(dataArray);
})

var payload = {
  "temperature": 2,
  "humidity": 80
};

function startGraph() {
   //Graph code
}
```

If button is pressed after 5 seconds, array element will still be added but not plotted (i.e, any sensor data coming in after 5 seconds will not be plotted)

Is there a way to read the newly added array elements and continue plotting the graph?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on what you mean by "read newly added array elements and continue plotting"? Read them to where, do what with them?

Comment: check this if it is useful https://jsfiddle.net/3x3fwszo/ calling `startGraph()` on click function

Comment: @ewolden: To also plot all of those values that were added to the dataArray after the timeout of 5 seconds i.e, after the chart was initialised

Comment: @Deep3015: This makes the graph to restart every time a new element is added which should not be the case while displaying streaming temperature data. Is there any other way?

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra yes, use `addPoint`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `addPoint` method of the series to add points dynamically.

```
$("#addToArray").click(function() {
  //myChartTemperature and myChartHumidity are created  globally in your code
  //so I check if they exist here
  if(myChartTemperature) {
    myChartTemperature.series[0].addPoint(payload.temperature);
  }
  if(myChartHumidity){
    myChartHumidity.series[0].addPoint(payload.humidity);
  }
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms91r4pr/2/)

Comment: Could you please recheck? I see no graph. It says myChartTemperature is undefined in the console.

Comment: It works fine when I press after the graph is loaded. I'll check why it does not work before the graph is loaded.

Comment: give more time to add point after forming chart  check this https://jsfiddle.net/ms91r4pr/3/

Comment: Also, since the original fiddle has a slice of 8, I assume that is the desired behaviour. So a `removePoint` if there are more than 8 points is probably a good idea.

Comment: I would simply define missing variables. Defining global variables without `var` is not the best idea. Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ms91r4pr/4/

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra Ah now I see. You already used `addPoint`. It is just that when you update `dataArray` it will not update other arrays automatically

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra As I can understand this fiddle is for demo purpose only. If you receive the real data from an API then just push it right to the series using `addPoint`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you want the graph to move with the time you can pass `true` to the as the 3rd parameter to `addPoint` like this: `myChartTemperature.series[0].addPoint(payload.temperature, true /*do redraw*/, myChartTemperature.series[0].data.length > 20 /*shift the graph after 20 points*/);`